# How to call a component to its self event - DELPHI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to create a procedure that will set its own property. Please refer to the sample code. I am using DELPHI XE

*sample:*

```
procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.ChangeText;
    begin
      if self.Text = '' then
      begin
      Self.Text := '0';
      end;
    end;

//Edit 14
procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.MyDBLabeledEdit14Exit(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    ChangeText
    end;

//Edit 15
procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.MyDBLabeledEdit15Exit(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    ChangeText
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach makes little sense to me.  If I understand what you're trying to do, here's what you should do instead:

- Click on one of the controls (let's call it `DBEdit1` to make it easy).
- Switch to the Object Inspector's Events tab, and double-click the OnExit event.
- In the Code Editor, you'll see

  ```
  procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.DBEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  begin

  end;
  ```
- Edit that code to:

  ```
  procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.DBEdit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Edit: TDBEdit; // replace with your actual control class
  begin
    // Replace TDBEdit with the your actual control class
    Edit := (Sender as TDBEdit);
    if Edit.Text = '' then
      Edit.Text := '0';
  end;
  ```
- Go back to the Object Inspector and change the name of the `OnExit` event from `DBEdit1Exit` to `AllDBEditExit`.
- In the Form Designer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> each of the controls you want to have the same behavior to select them all.
- In the Object Inspector Events tab, click the drop-down list in the `OnExit` event and choose `AllDBEditExit` as the event name.

Comment: I would suggest tweaking the `OnExit` handler to not call the `as` operator multiple times, as that will perform a redundant lookup at runtime. Call it one time and save the result in a local variable, eg: `procedure TCarcassUpdateForm.AllDBEditExit(Sender: TObject); var Edit: TDBEdit; begin Edit := Sender as TDBEdit; if Edit.Text = '' then Edit.Text := '0'; end;`